# Creating a custom cell increment when pasting a formula with cell reference

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula

I have a report in excel about customers answering a set of questions with a rating from 1-5. This is the current table: (The upper letters and the numbers at the left side only represent the cells and is not included in the data)

```
  A     B    C   D   E
1 Name  Age  Q1  Q2  Q3
2 John  19   5   4   5
3 Bob   18   3   2   5
4 Jess  20   3   5   4
```

How do I get the cells and display the values like this:

```
  A     B   C   D
1 John  19  Q1  5
2 John  19  Q2  4
3 John  19  Q3  5
4 Bob   18  Q1  3
5 Bob   18  Q2  2
6 Bob   18  Q4  5
7 Jess  20  Q1  3
8 Jess  20  Q2  5
9 Jess  20  Q3  4
```

How do I create a custom cell increment when pasting a formula with cell reference?

My formula:

> `="INSERT into tableName Values ('" & A 2& "', " & B2 & ", " & C1 & ", " &C2& "); INSERT into tableName Values ('" & A2 & "', " & B2 & ", " & D1 & ", " &D2& "); INSERT into tableName Values ('" & A2 & "', " & B2 & ", " & E1 & ", " &E2& ");"`

Formula value:

> `INSERT into tableName Values ('John, 19, Q1, 5'); INSERT into tableName Values ('John', 19, Q2, 4); INSERT into tableName Values ('John', 19, Q3, 5);`

I have to paste this to get the Q1, Q2 and Q3 from all names. The problem is when I paste the formula to the next row, it only increments the cell reference one row..

Comment: This seems a marco thing. Do you have to put them together in one sheet?

Comment: Yes. I'll check on that macro thing.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw some answers in another site.. If you do not want to increment a specific cell in a formula, just go to your formula and highlight the cell you don't want to increase and press F4.

Pressing F4 will cycle through the possible dynamic/absolute combinations:

1. A1; column & row dynamic
2. $A$1; column & row absolute
3. A$1; column dynamic, row absolute
4. $A1; column absolute, row dynamic

Answer (score 1):

`Offset` is your fiend in this case

Putting your example data in sheet1, and these formulas in Sheet2...

```
A1: =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,INT(ROW()-1)/3+1,0)
A2: =OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,INT(ROW()-1)/3+1,0)
A3: =OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$1,0,MOD((ROW()-1),3))
A4: =OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$1,INT(ROW()-1)/3+1,MOD((ROW()-1),3))
```

copy these down through row 9, and you will see that data in your second table

`INT(ROW()-1)/3+1` will increase from 1, but only increase every 3 rows
`MOD((ROW()-1),3)` returns 0,1 and 2, in sequence every row